# WP CRON job not firing callback function, but function is working when called from elsewhere

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

## The problem

I'm making a plugin. I have a function which goal is to loop throught every post of a given `post_type`, and store a given metafield value in a different table, along with the ID of the post and the date of the day. To give you some context, it's to keep tracks of products prices.
The function works perfectly when called "manually" with the `admin_menu` hook, I got my table populated with all the data.
Now I want this function to run once every day so I set up a CRON JOB with `wp_schedule_events`. WP controls shows the schedule CRON JOB, but the callback function is never executed, and there's no errors, no log whatsoever :/

## The Code

The way I scheduled the CRON JOB

```
function schedule_price_curve_update( $args ) {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'update_product_price_curve') ) {
        $time=time();
        $time=$time+60;
        wp_schedule_event($time, 'daily', 'update_product_price_curve', $args );
    }
}
```

My callback function to insert data to the dedicated table, and the hook for the CRON Job.

```
function bulk_update_product_price_curve( $setup_table_name) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'bons-plans',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );
    $posts_array = get_posts( $args );
    
    global $wpdb;     
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . $setup_table_name;       
    $date = date('Y/d/m');
    
    foreach( $posts_array as $post_array ){
        $price = get_post_meta( $post_array->ID, 'prix-promo', true);
        $wpdb->insert($table_name, array('product_id' => $post_array->ID, 'date' => $date, 'product_price' => $price));;
    }
    
}

add_action( 'update_product_price_curve', 'bulk_update_product_price_curve' );
```

The `$table_name` will be setup by user in the admin setting page of the plugin. As of now I set the $arg of the `schedule_price_curve_update( $args )` manually. No probleme on this part. Again, WP Control assure me the job is scheduled with the right arguments.

If anyone have any idea of why my callback function is not firing ? That's kind of frustrating as there's no error or nothing to give me any hint on why this isn't working... So there's also that : how can I debug this ?

Comment: Where is the call to schedule_price_curve_update?

Comment: To test if the job was working, I called the function from my plugin with the admin menu hook, so the function is called when I load the plugin's admin menu page :/